# Why does blueprint css define a div.class and class with the same styling?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, blueprint-css

In the linked code for the blueprint CSS framework, there is a style defined for a `div.class` selector and just the `.class` selector.  Isn't this redundant?  Or is there a more subtle reason for defining the class with two selectors?

https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/blueprint/src/grid.css (lines 229-235)

```
/* In case you need to add a gutter above/below an element */
div.prepend-top, .prepend-top {
  margin-top:1.5em;
}
div.append-bottom, .append-bottom {
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I've not used Blueprint, but then if you choose to override either `div.prepend-top` *or* `.prepend-top`, only that selector's styles will be overridden.

That means doing this:

```
.prepend-top { margin-top: 1em; }
```

Will leave the styles for `<div>`s with that class unaffected (still a 1.5-em top margin), because `div.prepend-top` is a more specific selector and so will take precedence for `<div>` elements.

And doing this:

```
div.prepend-top { margin-top: 1em; }
```

Will leave the styles for other elements with that class unaffected, because of the `div` type selector. Likewise for the `append-bottom` class.

Again I've not used Blueprint, but I think it has something to do with how it expects your HTML to be structured.

Comment: I see, that makes alot of sense (doing it for more or less specificity).  Thanks!